# Code coverage in TFS build templates

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a build template which was created with VS2010 or lower version of VS. Now, I have VS2013. I want to enable code coverage for that build, but I do not see such option as in this page:

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/06/08/code-coverage-during-tfs-2012-build/

If I select the default build template when creating a new build definition - then I see the option to enable code coverage.

Am I missing something?

Another question if I should re-create (with VS2013) all my custom build templates that were created with VS2010 or lower versions in order for everything to work fine and in order too see the features such as code coverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should recreate your build in 2013 and make sure that you only use custom PowerShell. The new build system in TFS 2015 does not use xaml builds.

If you use PowerShell to customize you will minimize conversion cost.